# Django serializer - unable to pass correct data in Many to Many relation with nested serializers

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to solve this problem :

A user can add skills to his profile and other user can upvote the skill on his profile .

I have implemented adding skills in system .
Now next I am trying build adding a skill (which is already added in system by admins ) to be added to the user profile .

But in my POST API , i am always getting following error

```
{
    "user": {
        "user": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Body Input :

```
{
    "user":{
         "username": "USERN",
         "email": "diahu@gail.com",
         "first_name": "",
          "last_name": ""
    },
    "new_user_skill":
        {
             "id": 1,
             "skill_name": "C"
        }
}
```

My View :

```
 elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = { 'user':request.data.get('user'),'skill_item':request.data.get('new_user_skill')}
        serializer = UserSkillSerializer(data=data)
        print("-------------------> serializer ")
        print(serializer)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Model :

```
class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username': {
                'validators': [],
            }
        }    


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserModelSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

        def create(self, validated_data):

            user_serializer = UserModelSerializer.create(UserModelSerializer(),validated_data = validated_data)
            user,created=UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=user_serializer)
            return user

class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)
    skill_item = SkillSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserSkill
        fields= '__all__'

    def create (self,validated_data):

        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserProfileSerializer.create(UserProfileSerializer(),validated_data= user_data)
        skill_data = validated_data.pop('skill_item')
        skill_item   = SkillSerializer.create(SkillSerializer(),validated_data=skill_data)
        user_skill, created = UserSkill.objects.update_or_create(user=user,skill_item=skill_item)

        return user_skill
```

Serializer :

```
class SkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Skill
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'skill_name': {
                'validators': [],
            }
        }  

class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username': {
                'validators': [],
            }
        }    


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=UserModelSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

        def create(self, validated_data):

            user_serializer = UserModelSerializer.create(UserModelSerializer(),validated_data = validated_data)
            user,created=UserProfile.objects.update_or_create(user=user_serializer)
            return user

class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)
    skill_item = SkillSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserSkill
        fields= '__all__'

    def create (self,validated_data):

        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserProfileSerializer.create(UserProfileSerializer(),validated_data= user_data)
        skill_data = validated_data.pop('skill_item')
        skill_item   = SkillSerializer.create(SkillSerializer(),validated_data=skill_data)
        user_skill, created = UserSkill.objects.update_or_create(user=user,skill_item=skill_item)

        return user_skill
```

I have removed validators (not sure if that is correct approach )

**Edit 1**

I have edited much of my code as per answer (i have studied and implemented reverse relation ) , facing one Not Null constraint even though I have **null=True**

My Updated code :

Serializer :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email','user_profile')


class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    skill_item = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserSkill
        fields= ('user', 'skill_item')
```

Views :

elif request.method == 'POST':

```
    current_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data.get('user')) # get the user key
    user_profile_id = current_user.user_profile.pk # get the user profile from reverse relation in model
    data = { 'user':user_profile_id,'skill_item':request.data.get('skill_id')}
    serializer = UserSkillSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Model :

```
# This class will more or less map to a table in the database and defines the many to many relationship between user-skill, this is our intermediate model
class UserSkill(models.Model):
    """ A Model for representing skill in user profile """
    unique_together = (('user', 'skill_item'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='current_user_skills')

    skill_item = models.ForeignKey(Skill,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.skill_item.skill_name)

# this class adds a Many to Many field in existing django-rest auth UserProfile class for  user and his/her skills 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User',unique=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_profile')
    user_skills = models.ManyToManyField(
            Skill,
            through='UserSkill',
            through_fields=('user','skill_item'),null=True
        )
#create user profile signal handler
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**Error :**

> ```
> return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\code\django\wantedly\src\wantedly_webapp\views\AllViews.py", line
> ```
>
> 61, in user_skill_collection
>       serializer.save()
>
> IntegrityError at /api/v1/user/skills/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   wantedly_webapp_userskill.skill_item_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is generated because the `UserProfileSerializer` has a `user` field that expects a whole user definition. In general I believe you mix the concepts "user profile" / "user" in your serializers, which creates confusion.

Once you have created a `User` with its associated `UserProfile` and a `Skill`, a way to add the `Skill` to the `UserProfile` is by selecting them by primary key:

```
class UserSkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    skill_item = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserSkill
        fields= ('user', 'skill_item')
```

The POST data to assign a `Skill` to a `UserProfile` would then be:

```
{
    "user": 3,  # PK of the UserProfile, not the User!
    "skill_item": 42  # PK of the SkillItem you want to assign
}
```

Comment: This is great solution .I can imagine this that I should create a UserProfile as soon as a new user is created . I am not sure how to do this because I am still learning serializers . Secondly , for this api how can I get the pk of the UserProfile ? I am using django rest-auth

Comment: You can create a profile for each new user created automatically using a signal handler, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488974/django-create-user-profile-on-user-creation
To get the pk of the `UserProfile` you can for example add a field to the `UserSerializer` showing the id of its profile. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations.

Comment: I just learnt about reverse relation and implemented it . I am able to get UserProfile id and create a user profile on a New user creation,but now I am facing Integrity constraint .Please check my Edit - 1